# How make search in mysql php oop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have mysql database of products with id, p_name(FULL TEXT), country, company, price. i need to make dynamic search on website. for now i have such problem when i query the result i have to type exact match of name in database. i tried to put %:query% but when i execute the result is empty

Model:

```
public function getSearchResult($query){
        $params = [
            'query' => $query,
        ];
        // Prepare statement
        $search = $this->db->row("SELECT id, p_name FROM product WHERE p_name LIKE :query", $params);

        return $search;

        }
```

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(){

        $result = $this->model->getSearchResult($_POST['search']);

        $vars = [
            'result' => $result,
        ];
        $this->view->render('Search', $this->vars + $vars);
    }
```

DB Class:

```
public function query($sql, $params = []){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        if(!empty($params)){
            foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
                if (is_int($val)) {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                } else {
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
                $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val, $type);
            }
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function row($sql, $params = []){
        $result = $this->query($sql, $params);
        return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: `$search = $this->db->row("SELECT id, p_name FROM product WHERE p_name LIKE '%:query%'", $params);`

Comment: try $params = [
            ':query' => '%'.'$query.'%'
     ];

Comment: i tried this method but it returns empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `%` in your array value. Change your model code like below:

```
public function getSearchResult($query){
        $params = [
            ':query' => '%'.$query.'%', // change this line
        ];
        // Prepare statement
        $search = $this->db->row("SELECT id, p_name FROM product WHERE p_name LIKE :query", $params);

        return $search;

        }
```